# centos 7 nginx not accepting requests from outside networks

Tags: http, nginx, centos7, remote-access, firewall

I'v configured a Nginx server on centos 7 and it works properly from the browser on the server. but when I try from any remote clients it says that it can not connect. I'v tried to add http to firewalld services.

```
    sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
```

and the result is :

```
 target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh http https
  ports: 80/tcp 443/tcp 8000/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

but when from another node i try:

```
sudo  nmap -sT  {ip address}
```

I got:

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
443/tcp closed https
```

also if helpful, result of

```
sudo netstat -tulpn 

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17859/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1263/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12372/postgres      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1766/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      17859/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1263/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      12372/postgres      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1766/master         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           867/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                867/chronyd
```

also

```
sudo ufw status verbose

Status: inactive
```

and

```
sestatus

SELinux status:                 disabled
```

can anybody help me with this?